# Sorting query results by the order of items in provided conditions array in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am looking for a way to query a database with Mongoose based on an array of document IDs and return the results in the order in which they were presented to Mongoose within that array.

For example if I provided Mongoose with this array `["112", "111", "113"]`
and assuming that all the documents with these IDs exist the result will be an array of documents ordered accordingly as: `[{//112},{//111},{//113}]`

Just to be crystal clear, I don't need to sort the array by any specific document field - I am looking for a way to tell Mongoose to sort by the order of the IDs as presented in the conditions array itself. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering following data:

```
db.col.save({ a: "111"})
db.col.save({ a: "112"})
db.col.save({ a: "113"})
db.col.save({ a: "114"})
```

you can use Aggregation Framework's [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) to filter out all the items that are not present in specified array and the [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) with [$indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/index.html) to get the `index` property. Then you can [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) by that property and use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) to remove temporary field. Try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { a: { $in: ["112", "111", "113"] } }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            index: { $indexOfArray: [ ["112", "111", "113"], "$a" ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { index: 1 }
    },
    {
        $project: { index: 0, _id: 0 }
    }
])
```

Outputs:

```
{ "a" : "112" }
{ "a" : "111" }
{ "a" : "113" }
```

Comment: Thank you for the elegant solution. I've read that aggregate is the slowest querying method in MongoDB but for my specific use case it was the perfect solution.