# MongoDB: find all documents by an array of ids with results ordered by the id

Tags: mongodb, find

The title might not be clear, but basically I want to do a

```
db.collection.find({ _id: { $in: [ObjectId(a), ObjectId(b), ObjectId(c)] } })
```

while preserving the results in a,b,c order, so the first item in the results are doc A, then doc B, then doc C. `$in` doesn't seem to preserve that order and seemingly treats the input array as a set. Is there a way to do that purely with MongoDB methods?

Comment: This can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53647106/sorting-query-results-by-the-order-of-items-in-provided-conditions-array-in-mong/53659000#53659000

Comment: as suggested by link provided by @mickl - use cursor method sort().   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/

Comment: Thanks @mickl, that precisely answers my question, I might as well accept it as an answer if you post it not as a comment.

Comment: @SándorVasas cool, that's not needed -  I can close this one and mark as duplicate